For Agnostic philosophers, 'God' is a placeholder for anything that science can not explain?

Bertrand Russell: As a philosopher, if I were speaking to a purely philosophic audience I should say that I ought to describe myself as
an Agnostic, because I do not think that there is a conclusive
argument by which one can prove that there is not a God. On the other
hand, if I am to convey the right impression to the ordinary man in
the street I think I ought to say that I am an Atheist, because when I
say that I cannot prove that there is not a God, I ought to add
equally that I cannot prove that there are not the Homeric gods.

Karl Marx, as well as many other philosophers, simply avoided definitions of their views about God.
Is it a prudent science to put the definition of God outside the scope?

There's some interesting answers that can be had regarding scientific realism vs insturmentalism.  However, I'm having trouble shaping it.  Your title says one thing.  The body asks a very different question (Is it prudent...).  The quote says a third thing.  I'm having trouble tying them together enough, and it makes me think I might be missing something about your question.  Is there perhaps a second paragraph that might tie the three together that could be edited in?

Those aren't the most important questions.

Presumably someone who believes that God is or explains anything that science can't explain must be either a theist or a lunatic, since there obviously exist many things that science can't explain. The other theists would probably disagree that God is/explains, e.g., what the longest cat in England as of the February 3, 1754 was doing at 8:35 AM. But we can all agree that there was a longest cat in England, and he was doing something.

Note that in their work they also didn't mention their taste concerning pistachio ice cream. Probably because this too was irrelevant to said work.

I am surprised at how politicized the view of 'God' in philosophy is. It feels like people talking about the place of Trump in the daily news, not the presence of God in philosophical studies.

Well in general I'd agree (ur last comment). But for this q u need to heed @CortAmmon's comment

I sometimes feel a bit disingenuous quoting a science fiction author on philosophy, but the attitude written by Robert Heinlein in Stranger in a Strange Land keeps coming up as a really useful phrasing.  It's written from the perspective of a man that was raised on Mars by Martians, and now has to make sense of human reality (and human language) on earth: "Short human words were never like a short Martian word — such as "grok" which forever meant exactly the same thing. Short human words were like trying to lift water with a knife.  /
And [God] had been a very short word."

However, this paragraph does not prove that Bertrand adheres to the principle of general rule.

@CortAmmon Your first comment above has some stuff in it; and is evidently one that many agree with.  I thought I'd try and expand  that to an(other) answer — I already wrote one. But then after starting to write it it occured to me you should so deleted it. So this is just a shout out that maybe you should try expanding that

The ontological/epistemological questions regarding theological verities that claim center-stage on a forum like this one are almost never the questions that engage people who "believe" (so-called) in God.
Framing Note

It is generally accepted that labeling bias produces conceptual distortion.
One does not call a muslim a "Mohammedan", or a native American a "red Indian". And this is not so much a question of a putdown by an intentional pejorative so much as simply ignorance.
Religious people rarely characterize themselves as believers in God but as something more specific and definite like Jew or Christian or even more specific — Catholic, Mormon etc.
Theist is an even worse mislabelling — no one who calls themself a theist, ever self-identifies that way other than in arguments with obstreperous atheists.
So I will stick to "religious" instead of "theist" and/or "believ(er) in God".

Religious people in the usual case, are typically focused on things like prayer, communion, baptism, confession, rites, mantras, breathing, meditation practices etc etc and their palpable (or otherwise) effects on their lives.
Asking them to worry about the epistemics/ontics that are fashionable out here is like going to a doctor in an emergency and instead of discussing the problem's history, symptoms, suggested regimen etc., to spend all the time asking whether the doctor is an educated doctor, whether his medical college was a good/accredited college, etc etc.
So which God are you talking about? The one who religious people orient around (Misnomer: 'believe in') or the one who experts disbelieve? They are not much related...
Put in the language more appropriate to this forum religious people have much less of anything like belief and more of something like seeking procedures,  practices and outlooks that give meaning, direction, well-being to their lives.
In summary

Beliefs are what you think is true;
Values are what you feel is important;
Actions are their resultant.

It is helpful to factorize human functioning into 3 dimensions — cognitive, affective, volitive.
It is found across times and cultures



Dimension
Bhagavad Gita
Gurdjieff's "3-brained being"




Cognitive
Jnana
Intellect


Affective
Bhakti
Emotions "heart"


Volitive
Karma
Body



Some examples of each:

Cognitive

"I believe in the resurrection of the dead and eternal life as taught by my faith."
"The principles of karma and dharma guide my understanding of justice and moral order in the universe."


Affective

"I feel a deep sense of peace and spiritual fulfillment when I pray."
"During worship, I am often moved to tears by a profound sense of love and closeness to God."


Volitive

"I choose to fast during Ramadan as a way to purify my soul and obey God's commandments."
"It is my duty to live according to the scriptures and partake in religious community services every week."



So, we may assert that philosophers are generally interested in the cognitive dimension and the religious in the affective and volitive dimensions.
There is little overlap

Note: The cognitive egs above are more likely said by philosophers of the religion than the religious themselves

Everything I say above is negated by some occasional 'argumentators' who would sit in a Richard Dawkins type of lecture and publicly prove to the speaker that they are right in 'believing' and the speaker wrong.  But they are the odd exceptions; not the rule.

There are many other problems with your question.

The idea of 'atheism' is essentially a Christian one.  What about Buddhist, Jewish, Hindu, Taoist atheists?
The provenance of 'agnostic' is a problematic one. The word 'gnostic' dates to the early centuries of the Christian era, the word 'agnostic' to 1869 ie. the 19th century. Are you ok claiming that there were no agnostics between the 1st and the 19th century AD? And if you claim there were, how do you address the patent anachronism?


Added Later
I just saw this discussion between Richard Dawkins and Ayaan Hirsi Ali
which encapsulates what I earlier wrote better than I did:

14 min:
Dawkins: Christianity is obsessed with sin
Ali: Christianity is obsessed with love
Towards the end
Dawkins: I want the truth
Ali: I want redemption
Ali's closing note: Humanism took away Christianity. The vacuum was filled by the violence of Islamism.  What are you offering when you take away Christianity? Humanism has clearly not worked...
Dawkins: You want to cure a virulent virus by vaccinating with a milder virus, I want no virus


It's very clear that they are not disagreeing but talking at very different levels

"People who 'believe in' God in the usual sense are typically focused on things like prayer" - Regarding idealism vs materialism, Ulyanov Lenin famously said: "Only an idiot can be a consistent materialist".

Yes materialism was at its heyday in the 19th century: Dalton and a world made of billiard balls called atoms, Mendeleef and the neat 2-d arrangement of these balls and finally the sunset with Thomson and the electron. One could claim that the 100 fold table of dalton-mendeleef got replaced fir a few decades by electron,proton, neutron. But then the bottom fell out with zillions of 'elementary' socalled particles. After the 1950s anybody who believes in matter is either clueless or living out of phase in imaginary past. Curiously that includes a majority of physicists. Kuhn describes curiosity

That materialism (more correctly naturalism) is self-inconsistent I've written here. Though admittedly that answer needs to be cleaned up

Poor Rushi is so obsessed with his religious brainwashing, he is trying to imagine that modern science serves his myths. :)

@Groovy - Sometimes, those with No God, No Czar in their head are worse in life than those with brainwashed ones. It is better to grow up with the wrong values than with no values at all.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance Actually no values is a value (of super low value) Just as zero is a number — the smallest.  One of the early classes in metaphysics runs No metaphysics is bad metaphysics

What's triggered you I cant make out @Groovy. But anyways: Ive reworked the answer in the hope of being clearer.  If it was the comment re. 19th century being the heyday of materalism: That was a side comment in answer to another comment and is not germane to this question/answer

@Rushi - I appreciate your heroic effort, but this question is just one vote away from being closed. :(

We are the outliers out here @TheMatrixEquation-balance. I like to believe that if Socrates or Wittgenstein were to stumble into here, they would not just be closed and deleted but banned for life. See this answer. I regard it as an outstanding answer. Now see the writer's ban period .
Anyways your Accept is gratefully accepted !

@Rushi - Fighting stubborn conservatism is a noble cause :) And you have to accept some battle damage.

Well dunno on that one @TheMatrixEquation-balance!! I call myself a classic conservative in the original English. American sense that If it ain't broke don't fix it is a more sound default policy than Progress for the sake of Progress¡

@Rushi - It is an obvious fact that large corporations and entrenched academia can effectively block new ideas when they threaten their turf.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance I just came across this. I find it a neat conspective view of the tension between the progressive and conservative viewpoints — productively encouraging inquiry that may upset and and maintaining a stable environment with clear red lines

@Rushi - I don't know, I don't take it seriously. Can you take seriously the way a man looks at a woman when he is 18?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


For Agnostic philosophers, 'God' is a placeholder for anything that science can not explain?

Not necessarily.

Karl Marx, as well as many other philosophers, simply avoided definitions of their views about God.

Why name drop Marx just to say that he is irrelevant to the question...???

Is it a prudent science to put the definition of God outside the scope?

The other way around if a theist refuses to give a clear and concise definition of god or makes god so powerful that he is not bound by the laws of nature, then it's prudent to be agnostic, because it's not impossible that there exists a definition for a god that does actually exist/not exist. Or if you go by a definition such as omnipotent (all-mighty), omnipresent (everywhere at once) and omniscient (all-knowing), then they could phase in and out of our existence at will and hide all the traces of their existence from science.
Like for that you could manipulate the observer, the tool of their observation or if they get really good every atom of the universe that interacted in that event and thus changed because of it. Which would be, from the perspective of science, be borderline impossible, but hey you're thinking about an all-mighty, all-present being that is all-knowing about how things work, so if it exists in the first place that might not be a big deal.
You know if ever someone figured out how the universe works, god could end it and replace it with a more complex one. People would either think their ancestors just didn't have the tech to measure reliable (likely true), that they made mistakes (also likely true), that they misinterpreted their data (likely true) and if you have enough of these likely scenarios people are likely going to accept the new reality.
That's massively cheating from the perspective of science and within that framework it doesn't really get you anywhere other than a depression because all your work would be ultimately futile, but you can't conclusively prove or disprove it. So for better or worse they just ignore it and move on without the hypothesis of an O3-being (omnipotent,...).
So no god is not necessarily just a name for the unknown and god might not just hide within the scientifically unexplained, that's just one particular way where to look at it without discarding our current knowledge of the world.

What about Hegel's Absolute Spirit? He seemingly embraces the idea of "studying the patterns of the unknown".  If we don't know what, why or how, we can still learn the direction and purpose of it.

We don't have a rigorous definition of 'god', any more than we have a rigorous definition of 'peace', 'love', 'beauty', or for that matter 'pornography'. These are 'universal linguistic standards' meant to guide human praxis in particular ways without themselves being defined. They are Wittgenstein's metre-rule writ large:

There is one thing of which one can state neither that it is 1 metre
long, nor that it is not 1 metre long, and that is the standard metre
in Paris. But this is, of course, not to ascribe any remarkable
property to it, but only to mark its peculiar role in the game of
measuring with a metre-rule. ["Philosophical Investigations" §50]

There is no method in material science for measuring linguistic elements. Scientists measure aspects of the world that are pointed to by linguistic elements, but in the case of universal standards (which are merely adopted) there's nothing to point at which cannot be questioned. Scientists who believe in God or who are properly agnostic mainly ignore God for practical purposes. The tension lies between science-antagonistic theists and science-oriented atheists who respectively want to elevate the standard to a material fact or reduce the standard to 'mere' language.
When philosophers address religion, it's usually to examine the separation between religious ideals and religious praxis. Marx, for instance, had no objection to the ideals of religious faith (many of which he echoed in secular terms); he objected to the Christian praxis of instructing adherents to hope for rewards in the afterlife, not in this life. He could have invoked God to this end — a practice common among church reforms and certain types of social activists — but his interests lied in societal reform, not religious reform. getting into discussions about God would merely have distracted from his main point.

Sorry. It does not make sense to me. In any scientific research and calculations you will have unknown variables that you explicitly or silently put out of scope.
For example:

We accept that we don't know how life on Earth started, but we can study how this life developed.
We don't know how to explain the singularity phase of our universe, but we could study conditions in the universe 1 second after the Big Bang.


There is a wonderful definition of Love in the Catechism: "To will the good of another." Cheryl Abram wrote about Love in her post: Love: A Wolf In Sheep's Clothing. It also covers Peace and Beauty.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance: Of course there are hidden variables that get wrapped up in the error term, but that misses the point. Consider… We can certainly research 'sexual arousal' because that is primarily biology: hormones and blood-flow patterns and the release of adrenaline and certain brain chemicals. However, we can't do the same with 'romantic love' because love is a set of conventions, attitudes, and social relationships. The conceptual world does not reduce easily or neatly to the biological world (we cannot reduce romantic love to sexual arousal).

We assert that 'love' exists, as an ideal we all reach for, and 'scientific' investigations into it merely cheapen it.

Your suggestion seems to be that God is synonymous with the set of all things not explained by science. That is clearly not correct. Aside from the  morning activities of the longest English cat cited by GS, there are many phenomena not yet explained by science, which we would not equate with the idea of God. God can be considered as a catch-all explanation for a sub-set of things not explained by science- a subset that has diminished over the centuries and religion has  ceded ground to science.

"God bows to Math"

I guess that's an insultingly ignorant assumption that fails to capture the bold spirit of agnostic inquiry. Agnostics do not treat 'God' as some semantic placeholder or God of the gaps fallacy. They reject the idea of punting difficult questions to a supernatural answer when science currently has no explanation.
True agnosticism maintains that the question of God's existence is either meaningless or impossible to answer definitively based on the available evidence. It is not a cop-out or an argument from ignorance. It is a rational position that says - in the absence of convincing proof either way, we simply reserve judgment on the matter. They don't fill gaps with God.
The agnostic position is that the existence or non-existence of God is unknown and perhaps unknowable. They find the claims and proofs of both religious believers and doctrinaire atheists to be unconvincing. It's the rational, skeptical position of refusing to accept an extraordinary claim without sufficient evidence.
But "people of faith", yes, they constantly move the semantic goalposts and redefine their deities as science progresses. Well, and they are right in a way, churches need to maintain money and power. ;)

"existence or non-existence of God is unknown" - This statement is only meaningful when you apply it to the real study of the world. "How the universe got created". "How life has started". "Who drives the evolution".
